# can I run simultaneous Python scripts against xlwings?

Tags: parallel-processing, xlwings

Long story short: I have been struggling with xlwings, getting random errors when I tried to fill an existing spreadsheet template -- multiple unique instances of it! -- with values from different simultaneously executing Python scripts. So think of multiple scripts that will fill a worksheet in a template (driving a pivot table/chart) with unique data that has identical shapes. For example, suppose you have weather data in identical formats from 10 places, and you want to use those data to create 10 different xlsx files with pivot tables, based on a common template.

Again, this works fine when running the scripts in sequence. But when running them in parallel (in Windows), using the "start" command from a batch file, random errors happen, and I am left with hanging Excel instances.

The errors look like shown below. Any other/better way/library to accomplish this? Else this won't scale...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Production.py", line 1246, in <module>
    UpdateXLSMasterTemplatesAndSave(stXLSTemp,stOutputFile,dfResults)
  File "Production.py", line 1124, in UpdateXLSMasterTemplatesAndSave
    ws.range('A1').options(index=True).value = dfIn
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2411, in value
    conversion.write(data, self, self._options)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 102, in write
    pipeline(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\framework.py", line 79, in __call__
    stage(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 73, in __call__
    ctx.range = ctx.range.resize(len(ctx.value), len(ctx.value[0]))
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2697, in resize
    return Range(self(1, 1), self(row_size, column_size)).options(**self._options)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1804, in __init__
    impl = cell1.sheet.range(cell1, cell2).impl
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1435, in range
    if cell2.sheet != self:
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1375, in __ne__
    return not self.__eq__(other)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1370, in __eq__
    and self.book == other.book
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 985, in __eq__
    and self.name == other.name
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1104, in name
    return self.impl.name
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 834, in name
    return self.xl.Name
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 198, in __getattr__
    v = getattr(self._inner, item)
  File "C:\Users\stats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 628, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147417848, 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.', None, None)
```

As described; tried to make sure I am using different physical files for the templates in each thread -- no effect...

PS/EDIT: For now I separated the updates of the XLSX templates from CSV files created via the Python scripts. This allows me to run a "sentinel" watching for the data to show up, and filling/saving them into the XLSX files one-at-a-time. That works, but still there should be a better way...

Comment: Alright, made some inroads I think (with special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032962/xlwings-excel-and-windows-task-scheduler-issues):

Before I hadn't set the "configure for..." option in Windows Scheduler to Windows 10; I set the Start-in directory on the Edit Action dialog to point-to the directory with the Python sources. Five consecutive tests completed correctly. 

Still not certain if the parallelization of XLWINGS will work because I rewrote the code to load-data-into-EXCEL in sequence and after new CSV files show up. Anyway, so far so good.